# SharePoint 2013 - Creating an Enterprise Wiki site

Tags: 2013, wiki

When I go to create a site and use the Enterprise Wiki Publishing template, I get "an unexpected error has occurred."  The SharePoint Publishing feature is activated.  I do not see anything specific in the error logs, not that I fully understand what they say anyway.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

From recollection, there are two places where 'Publishing' needs to be activated.

Have a check in Site Settings | Site Collection features (under Site Collection Administration) and check that 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' is activated.

Then also check in Site Settings | Manage site features (under Site Actions) and check that 'SharePoint Server Publishing' is activated.

I have a vague recollection that you might need to activate one before the other one displays, but do not recall which way around this was.